# Implicit Function Theorem when determinant equals zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The implicit function theorem states:

Let $F(x,y)$ be an $\mathbb{R}^k$ valued function of class $C^1$ on some neighborhood of a point $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ and let $B_{ij} = (\partial F_i/\partial y_j) (a,b)$.

Suppose that $F(a,b)=0$ and det $ B \neq 0$. Then there exist positive numbers $r_0, r_1$ such that for each $x$ in the ball $|x-a| < r_o$ there is a unique $y$ such that $|y-b|<r_1$ and $F(x,y)=0$.

**Question:**
Suppose we change the condition above to det $B =0$.
Can we conclude that for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$, there does **not** exist a unique $y$ close to $b$ such that $F(x,y)=0$?

Loosely speaking, can I conclude that I can't write $y=f(x)$ for some $f$?

Comment: Have you seem the constant rank theorem? If not, take a look.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can, perhaps you can't. Try
$$F(x,y) = x-y^2 \quad\text{and}\quad x-y^3$$
at the origin.

Comment: I can appreciate this counter example for $k=1$, but I am having a hard time crafting a higher dimensional example for "perhaps you can, perhaps you can't". For example, $n=1$ and $k=2$, I'm looking at $F(x,y,z) = (x+y^2+z^2, x+y^3+z^3)$ near the origin. Clearly the determinant is zero. But I'm not even sure how to even write $(y,z)$ as a function of $f(x)$, let alone determine the uniqueness of (y,z). If I just look at the first component $F_1 = x+y^2+z^2 = 0$ how do you even write (y,z) = f(x)? If I write $y= \pm \sqrt{-x-z^2}$, this is a function of x and z, not a function of just x.